# Searching for a value in a column, with multiple values, in Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Suppose I have a column which contains multiple values e.g Lets say we have a table which contains teacher's Name & departments (comma separated). In which a teacher can belong to many departments.

I want to search for the rows which contains the department starting with the letter typed in search field.

Right now I am using bw filter which works for only the first entry in the comma separated list (as it takes whole list as a single string).

Comment: Which `datatype` you use? Is the searching *locally* or you need to send the corresponding searching request to the server? Do you use searching dialog ([Advanced Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching)), [Toolbar Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching), both or some other custom searching?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am searching locally and using toolbar search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid don't provide you any possibility to custom operation like "begin with" searching in comma-separated substrings. So one have to use standard operation. On the other side one can subclass methods of `$.jgrid.from` object used by jqGrid during filtering. I posted already some other answers which demonstrates the technique. It's still not so easy. So I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/subclassStartsWith.htm) which demonstrates how to subclass `startsWith` method of `$.jgrid.from` so that it works in special way like you need, but only in special column (see the constant `"departments"` in the code below)

```
var oldFrom = $.jgrid.from;
$.jgrid.from = function (source, initalQuery) {
    var result = oldFrom(source, initalQuery),
        old_startsWith = result.startsWith;

    result.startsWith = function (f, v) {
        if (f !== "departments") {
            return old_startsWith.call(result, f, v);
        }
        var self = result, val = (v === null) ? f : v, length = val.toString().length;
        self._append(
            'jQuery.map(' +
                self._getStr('jQuery.jgrid.getAccessor(this,\'' + f + '\')') +
                '.split(","),function(item) {if (item.substr(0,' + length + ')===' +
                self._getStr('"' + self._toStr(v) + '"') +
                ") { return item; }}).length > 0"
        );
        self._setCommand(self.startsWith, f);
        self._resetNegate();
        return self;
    };
    return result;
};
```

If one filter the column "departments" for the string "d2" one will see the following results

[image]

Comment: I went through other answers but was not able to achieve the desired functionality. But above code worked like charm! :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Vivek: Small common remark: I see that you never used [voting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) (arrow up button on the lest part of answer or question). You have right to vote up to 30 answers or questions **per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213)). By voting you gives tips to searching engine and help other users of stackoverflow to find the information on stackoverflow. *So if you want help other people you should use your voting right and vote all information of stackoverflow which you find helpful and interesting and which you would recommend other*.